# select rows from a dataframe that do not match the query

Tags: r

As you can see this selection with R, shows the rows that have status different than 'Open' and also have the following type BMW, VW and Benz. 
How can I make run the opposite selection of this query:

```
df= df[ df$status != "Open" & (df$Type) %in% c("BMW","VW","BENZ"), ]
```

Comment: Place it in braces and then do `!` i.e. `df[!(df$status != "Open" & (df$Type) %in% c("BMW","VW","BENZ")),]`

Comment: This also works , thank you so much @akrun !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @akrun suggested you can simply insert `!` outside parentheses to negate the whole sentence

```
df = df[ !(df$status != "Open" & df$Type %in% c("BMW","VW","BENZ")), ]
```

Or you can "distribute" the not operator:
[image: teste]

```
df = df[ df$status == "Open" | !(df$Type %in% c("BMW","VW","BENZ")), ]
```